# Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs

Tags: android, logcat, android-studio-3.0

I'm getting hundreds of **warn messages** in Logcat from Android Studio and I don't know what might be causing this message.

```
Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
```

filtering as **Info messages**, I also get hundreds of messages like this:

```
I/Counters: exceeded sample count in FrameTime
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing these messages and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caused by Google Play Services when it does not have adequate permission resulting continuous retries.

Try Removing Google Play Services App Data and verify it has usage and permission access to stop it.

To remove Google Play Services App Data: go to System Settings => Apps and search for Google Play services app, then go to storage to remove app data

(Thanks @phileo99)

Comment: To remove Google Play Services App Data:  goto System Settings => Apps and search for Google Play services app, then goto storage to remove app data

Comment: It's actually happening on a brand new Pixel 8 which I just set up.  I doubt clearing Google Play Services will solve that....

Comment: Same issue as IgorGanapolsky, clearing Google Play Services data didn't help

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky and benjamin New device has a higher chance of new updates which might break permissions. try uninstalling updates to google play services and check. Also, the solution is not just clearing data. Permissions need to be reset too.

Comment: How do we reset the permissions?

Comment: @AhmedAlbarody go to settings > apps > your app > permissions > and enable any permission which is in denied section