# Flutter throws SecurityException when working with Google Maps Platform

Tags: flutter, google-maps, gradle

1-. Use case.

I’m using the google_maps_flutter package, in a Flutter and Dart project. Version is google_maps_flutter: ^2.4.0

When I call to the GoogleMaps widget in Flutter:

[image]

the following SecurityException is thrown:

```
    E/GoogleApiManager( 5028): Failed to get service from broker. 
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028): java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at m.cpc.q(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:180)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at m.cno.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:54)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/GoogleApiManager( 5028):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
D/EGL_emulation( 5028): eglCreateContext: 0x7281d4cf23d0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 5028): Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.gms.maps#com.google.android.gms, may result in stale flags.
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 5028): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: m.fdz: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ckg{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 5028):     at m.gso.s(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:21)
```

2-. Implemented API key

I followed the guide described in the google_maps_flutter package (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter), the guide for installing Google Maps SDK in Flutter (https://developers.google.com/maps/flutter-package/config?authuser=0#step_1_install_the_required_software), and the ‘Maps SDK for Android Quickstart’ documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) ->

i) GMP API key generated
The api key related to Maps API is the fourth one ->

[image]

… with the following api key ->

[image]

… and restrictions ->

[image]

[image]

ii) the android manifest.xml is ->

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <application
       android:label="appname"
       android:name="${applicationName}"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true"
           android:launchMode="singleTop"
           android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


           <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
           <meta-data
             android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
             android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
             />


           <meta-data
               android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
               android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
               />


           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
            This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="flutterEmbedding"
           android:value="2" />


       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}"/>


   </application>
</manifest>
```

iii) the settings.graddle is ->

[image]

iv) the secrets.properties is ->

[image]

V) the local.defaults.properties is ->

[image]

vi) the android/build.gradle is ->

[image]

vii) the app/build.gradle is ->

```
plugins {
   id "com.android.application"
   id "kotlin-android"
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
   id "com.google.gms.google-services"
   id "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin"
}


def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
   localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
       localProperties.load(reader)
   }
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   flutterVersionCode = '1'
}


def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
   flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
   namespace "com.byroomnumber.brnapp"
   compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
   ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion


   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }


   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = '1.8'
   }


   sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }


   defaultConfig {
       // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
       applicationId "com.example.appName"
       // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
       // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 34
       multiDexEnabled true
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
   }


   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
   buildFeatures{
       buildConfig true
   }


}


flutter {
   source '../..'
}


dependencies {
   implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.7.1")
   implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.21"
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
}


secrets {
   // Optionally specify a different file name containing your secrets.
   // The plugin defaults to "local.properties"
   propertiesFileName = "secrets.properties"


   // A properties file containing default secret values. This file can be
   // checked in version control.
   defaultPropertiesFileName = "local.defaults.properties"


   // Configure which keys should be ignored by the plugin by providing regular expressions.
   // "sdk.dir" is ignored by default.
   ignoreList.add("keyToIgnore") // Ignore the key "keyToIgnore"
   ignoreList.add("sdk.*")       // Ignore all keys matching the regexp "sdk.*"
}
```

3. Expected results

The map is correctly rendered in a device connected via usb, although the exception is thrown.
If an apk is generated and installed on the device, the map is not rendered, and the exception is thrown.

4. Do you try using other devices?

Yes. I verified this process in a SMA426B and  and a MiT11

Comment: Please checkout this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77884292/19807154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacting with Google Maps Support, the problem is on their side: it is a bug.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091313

I have been informed that in next releases, the issue will be solved.

Comment: Thank you Rafael! This answer helped a lot! I have been searching for this error initally... E/GoogleApiManager( 5028): java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add INTERNET permission, add this line to androidManifes.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/network-ops/connecting), giving an explicit permission is not required anymore... I will try your proposed solution anyway...

Comment: @RafaelVizcaino I don't see the docs mentioned that it's not required. In fact, it's [needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55603979/13625293)

Comment: I tested your solution: I added both permissions, erased the caché and restarted Intellij. The same exception has been thrown

Comment: check permissions, update google play services and make sure that your application is properly configured to use google play services @RafaelVizcaino

Comment: @HasanToufiqAhamed, as I documented in the question, the version of the google play services is 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'... you are right, it must be related to Google play Services... am I implementing the gradle dependency well? The way I am including it are located in points 2 - iii) and 2 - viii).

Answer (score 0):

In you project level gradle change version of google play services to 4.3.15 in Plugins section.

```
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
```

Comment: I included the aforementioned downgrade of the google-services version... the result is still the same. I completed the question with a more detailed response from terminal -> see next answer. Thanks, @Ubaid ur Rehman Soomro !

Answer (score 0):

In order to give a more detailed information to the problem, I enclose the previous and forward information given in terminal, in addition to the error itself:

```
D/ConnectivityManager( 2402): StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4322)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4364)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4746)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4716)] [m.fbc.h(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:41)] [m.fbc.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:140)] [com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.hz.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:7)] [com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1157)] [com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.logInitialization(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:16)] [com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.bp(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:75)] [m.bcb.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:21)]
D/MapsInitializer( 2402): loadedRenderer: LATEST
D/zzcc    ( 2402): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Android Maps SDK( 2402): Google Play services package version: 240315038
I/Google Android Maps SDK( 2402): Google Play services maps renderer version(maps_core): 234210304
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter( 2402): Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10486; state: ENABLED
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
D/ConnectivityManager( 2402): StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4322)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallbackForUid(ConnectivityManager.java:4886)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4853)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4827)] [m.azp.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:53)] [m.ayw.e(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:34)] [m.ayt.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)] [m.amc.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:133)] [com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.phoenix.u.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)] [m.ale.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:3)] [m.azi.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:131)] [m.alg.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:12)] [m.esa.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:9)] [m.iph.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:14)] [m.esb.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:44)] [m.caw.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:6)] [m.cci.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:8)] [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)] [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)] [m.cbt.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:42)] [java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)]
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
I/PlatformViewsController( 2402): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 0
I/PlatformViewsController( 2402): PlatformView is using SurfaceProducer backend
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402): Failed to get service from broker. 
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402): java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2438)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2422)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2405)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2347)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at m.cqy.q(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:180)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at m.cpk.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:54)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/GoogleApiManager( 2402):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
D/OpenGLRenderer( 2402): eglCreateWindowSurface
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2402): [ImageReader-720x1510f22m4-2402-0](id:96200000004,api:1,p:2402,c:2402) queueBuffer: queued for the first time.
E/FrameEvents( 2402): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402): Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.gms.maps#com.google.android.gms, may result in stale flags.
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: m.few: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: cmc{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gua.s(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:21)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gua.get(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:5)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gwy.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gvt.h(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:10)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.fgk.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.fgr.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:5)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402): Caused by: m.few: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: cmc{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.fey.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:13)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gtx.e(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gtz.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:139)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.guz.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gua.q(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gua.k(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:96)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.gua.n(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:19)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.fbx.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:35)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyi.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:12)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.guz.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyj.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:12)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyr.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:36)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyv.g(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:20)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyf.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:83)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.guz.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyg.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:8)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cyr.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:36)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cys.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:25)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.coj.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:7)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cpi.s(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:48)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cpi.f(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:10)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cpi.j(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:177)
I/GoogleMapController( 2402): Installing custom TextureView driven invalidator.
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cpi.i(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cpk.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:82)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402): Caused by: m.cno: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: cmc{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.cqp.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:13)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     at m.coj.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 2402):     ... 10 more
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
E/GoogleMapController( 2402): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend( 2402): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
I/omnumber.brnap( 2402): Background concurrent copying GC freed 10187(905KB) AllocSpace objects, 34(1632KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 11MB/22MB, paused 2.768ms,345us total 145.905ms
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2402): [SurfaceTexture-0-2402-0](id:96200000005,api:1,p:2402,c:2402) queueBuffer: queued for the first time.
E/FrameEvents( 2402): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents( 2402): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

I suppose it is not a problem of Google Play Services, since it is correctly read...

Comment: I applied this solution as well -> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214824/too-many-flogger-logs-received-before-configuration-dropping-old-logs)... the result is the same...